# Cassandra Data storage: data directory space not equal to the space occupied

Tags: memory, cassandra, disk, nodetool, du

This is a beginners question on Cassandra Architecture.

I have a 3 node Cassandra cluster. The data directory is at $CASSANDRA_HOME/data/data. I've loaded a huge data set. I did a `nodetool flush` and then           `nodetool tablestats` on the table I loaded the data. This says the total space occupied is around 50GiB. I was curious and checked the size of my data directory `du $CASSANDRA_HOME/data/data` on each of the nodes,which shows around 1-2GB on each. How could the data directory be less than the space occupied by a single table? Am I missing something? My table is created with `replication factor 1`

Comment: 50Gb of what kind of data? Compression is playing a huge factor here.

Comment: My question was more towards, shouldn't it reflect the same at both places even when it's compressed?

Comment: @xmas79 Compression is not enabled.

Comment: Was compression disabled since the beginning? Please post the YAML configuration

Answer (score 0):

`du` gives out the true storage capacity used by the paths given to it.  This is not always directly connected to the size of the data stored in these paths.

Two main factors mix up the output of `du` compared to any other storage usage information you might get (e. g. from Cassandra).

1. `du` might give out a smaller number than expected because of two reasons: ⓐ It combines hard links.  This means that if the paths given to it contain hard linked files (I won't explain hard links here, but this term is a fixed one for Unix*ish operating systems so it can be looked up easily), these are counted only once while the files exist multiple times.  ⓑ It is aware of sparse files; these are files which contain large (sometimes huge) areas of empty space (zero-bytes).  In many Unix*ish file systems these can be stored efficiently, depending on how they have been created.
2. `du` might give out a larger number than expected because file systems have some overhead.  To store a file of *n* bytes, *n* + *h* bytes need to be stored because of this.  *h* depends on the file system and its configuration.  The most important factor is that file systems typically store files in a block structure.  If a file isn't exactly the size of a multiple of the block size of the file system, the last needed block is still allocated completely by this file, so some of its size if wasted.  `du` will show the whole block as allocated because, in fact, it is.

So in your case Cassandra might talk about space occupied of 50GiB but a lot of it might be empty (never written-to) space.  This might be stored in a sparse file on the file system which in fact only uses 2GiB of storage size (which `du` shows).